# Constant term identity and the Grassmannian Gr(2,6)

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions

The following conjecture is motivated by two different presentations of the affine cone over Grassmannian $Gr(2,6).$  One as a GIT quotient of $Hom(\mathbb{C}^2, \mathbb{C}^6)//SU(2)$ and the other as an affine variety defined by ${6 \choose 2} = 15$ Plucker coordinates, ${4 \choose 2} = 15$ Plucker relations, and ${6 \choose 6} = 1$ syzygy.  Any thoughts on its proof (or disproof), or how to "fix" the left-hand side to give a full equality would be appreciated.

Conjecture: The coefficients of $t^{4k}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ in the expansion of the LHS and RHS of
$$ \frac{1}{(1- t^6)}  \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint \frac{dz}{z} (1 - z^2) PE( i_E) =  \frac{1}{(1- t^6)}  \prod_{1\le i < j \le 6} \frac{\left( 1- u_i^{-1} u_j^{-1} t^4 \right)}{(1-u_i u_j t^2)} + t^6 + t^{12} +t^{24} -\frac{t^{48}}{\left(t^{12}-1\right)^2}$$
agree, where $$i_E = t^6 \chi_3(z) + \left (t \chi_f(u) - t^5 \chi_{\bar{f}}(u) \right) \chi_2(z)$$
$$PE(i_E) = \frac{1}{(1 - t^6 z^2)(1 - t^6)(1 - t^6 z^{-2})} \prod_{1 \le i <j \le 6} \frac{(1 - t^5 z u_i^{-1} )(1 - t^5 z^{-1} u_i^{-1})}{(1 - tz u_i)(1 - t z^{-1} u_i)}$$
here $\chi_f(u) = \sum_{i=1}^{6} u_i, \qquad \chi_{\bar{f}}(u) = \sum_{i=1}^6 u_i^{-1}$ are the characters of the fundamental and anti-fundamental representations of $SL_6(\mathbb{C})$ and we have taken $\prod_{i=1}^{6} u_i = 1.$  $\chi_3(z) = z^2 + 1 + z^{-2}, \qquad \chi_2(z) = z + z^{-1}$ are the characters of the adjoint and fundamental representations of $SU(2).$  The Haar measure on $SU(2)$ is $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint \frac{dz}{z} (1 - z^2)$.  The integral simply picks off the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the series expansion in $t,z$.

There are some similarities with the elliptic beta integral of Spiridonov and its degenerations to the Nassrallah-Rahman and Askey-Wilson integrals.  However, it isn't obvious if they can be applied.